# Why doesn't the Devise registrations edit action need params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am learning a Rails course, and I have this in my routes

```
devise_for :users,
             path: '',
             path_names: { sign_up: 'register', sign_in: 'login', edit: 'profile', sign_out: 'logout' },
             controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'registrations' }
```

This will generates routes like

```
 edit_user_registration GET      /profile(.:format)      registrations#edit
```

In my view I just need to use `edit_user_registration_path` while normally it should be sth like `user_path(:id)`. If I write `edit_user_registration_path(1)` it will redirect to `.../profile.1`

As I know normal Rails edit route should have `params[:id]`. Why in this case it doesn't need and how `edit_user_registration_path(1)` generates `.../profile.1`?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the devise code you are asking about? `Update` method https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L46 and `create` method https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L16?  You can also look locally, which I like to do sometimes when I have questions like yours, by running  `bundle open devise`.  It might bug you about setting and editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routes don't need and don't take an ID parameter since they act on the current user which is stored in the session and not passed through the parameters.

Similarly if you wanted to create a controller that deals with items belonging to the current user you could do:

```
scope :user do
  resources :items, controller: :user_items
end

class UserItemsController
  before_action :authenticate_user
  # GET /user/items
  def index
    @items = current_user.items
  end
end
```

If you instead where building something like an admin interface where you can edit other users on the system an id param would be necessary.